# How can I pass the stringbuilder and display out in another class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I'm able to retrieve contact list for my contact picker, now how can I pass the stringbuilder and display out in another class. I thought of using intent but it didn't work.
Please help.

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("............"+ma.mCheckStates.size());
            for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)
                {
                if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                {
                     checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                     checkedcontacts.append("\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("..Not Checked......"+name1.get(i).toString());
                }

            }

          finish();

          Intent i = new Intent (this,SecondActivity.class);
         i.putExtra("str",checkedcontacts);
         startActivity(i);


        }       
    });
}
```

Error:

```
Intent i = new Intent (this,SecondActivity.class);
             i.putExtra("str",checkedcontacts);
             startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use StringBuilder.toString() to pass StringBuilder into Intent.

```
 Intent i = new Intent (this,SecondActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("str",checkedcontacts.toString());
 startActivity(i);
```

And you should use `finish();` after above code snippet. like

```
 //finish() //Remove this finish
 Intent i = new Intent (this,SecondActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("str",checkedcontacts.toString());
 startActivity(i);
 finish()
```

---

And in listner you can't use this as context object. You should use getApplicationContext() or ActivityName.this. Like

```
Intent i = new Intent (YourACTIVITYName.this, SecondActivity.class);

//OR

Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. Now this line has error. "Intent i = new Intent (this,SecondActivity.class);" It said constructor intent is undefined. What shd I do?

Comment: Err. Can you show me how to write getContext or Activityname? I'm new to android coding. Thanks

Comment: Answer updated. The activity name is the same name in which you are using this code snippet. see my update

Comment: Welcome and congs, you made it

Answer (score 0):

Yep, StringBuilder::toString(), see ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html